# javascript numeric variable display 0 instead of null

Tags: javascript

How do you make a numeric variable in javascript return 0 instead of null ?

I have a statistics table for users queries.. When a search criteria is 0 it is returned as null in the JSON object and displayed null in my table.. I was wondering if there's any workaround

**e.g**
`SELECT 
SUM( CASE WHEN`table`.`color`=  'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS  'Red',
SUM( CASE WHEN`Table`.`color`=  'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS  'Blue', ect....`

`var RedShirts = Stats.Red ;`
`$("#Red").text(RedShirts);`

It bothers me when it displays null instead of 0..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("#Red").text(RedShirts || 0);
```

Comment: Error: Cannot call method 'toString' of null 
Thanks anyway

Comment: `.toString` is not really needed imo.

Comment: And you can actually change it to a binary or for one less `|` :)

Comment: Or even just `+Redshirts`

Comment: Im COnfuseeeddd, well both of your answers are working.. I don't get the difference between || 0 or + ..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: @user3003977 `+` casts variable to the integer. `||` checks if left part is not null - if not, uses right one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#Red").text(+RedShirts);
```

Comment: What does the + before the a numeric variable means ?

Comment: @user3003977 - In JavaScript the `+` operator will cast the value after it into a number. (`null` --> `0`)

Comment: Thanks Derek, I accepted the above answer as he was first, but I can't say which one has better use. Your answer did as well what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(RedShirts){
      $("#Red").text(RedShirts);
}

else{
 $("#Red").text("0");}
```